# Visual studio falls at a time when i'm debugging project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

My solution consists of several projects and every time I compile the project that I need to change. But lately every compiler eventually leads to the collapse of the visual studio.
Anybody know why?

Comment: That is very less information to comment or answer any thing!

Comment: Your question its unclear. You need to post more info about your problem. Also, what you meant with: *every compiler*?

Comment: thanks for your comment. Sorry for the mistake I meant every time I compile not: every compiler. I'll explain: My solution contains several projects and every time I change one of them, to build a new dll I compile each project separately. My problem now is that when finished visual studio compiler, displays a message: "Looking for a solution to the problem" - stops responding and closes.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, it is because every time you compile the LESS filesbuilds css. cancel this feature will override the options